# Encoding issues appearing while reading in csv file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding

I am trying to read in a large csv that contains some lines that are irregular.  I've been receiving errors stating something to the effect of 'expecting 113 characters, encountered 114.'  I've tried discarding the rows with greater than the expected number of delimiting characters, but have subsequently encountered another error.  The code and error shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

f_name = 'some_file.txt'
    with open(f_name,'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

bad_lines= []
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.count('\t') != 112:
        bad_lines.append(i)
df = pd.read_csv(f_name,header=0,sep='\t',skiprows=bad_lines,error_bad_lines=False)
df.head()
```

This produces the following warnings and errors:

```
Skipping line 3332366: expected 113 fields, saw 168

Skipping line 3829308: expected 113 fields, saw 114

Skipping line 4819090: expected 113 fields, saw 114

Skipping line 4832856: expected 113 fields, saw 114

Skipping line 5170065: expected 113 fields, saw 114

Skipping line 5198811: expected 113 fields, saw 168

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ea2fca7ce11a> in <module>()
      1 df = pd.read_csv(f_name,header=0,sep='\t',skiprows=bad_lines,error_bad_lines=False)
----> 2 df.head()

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/displayhook.pyc in __call__(self, result)
    236                 self.write_format_data(format_dict, md_dict)
    237                 self.log_output(format_dict)
--> 238             self.finish_displayhook()
    239 
    240     def cull_cache(self):

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/displayhook.pyc in finish_displayhook(self)
     70         sys.stderr.flush()
     71         if self.msg['content']['data']:
---> 72             self.session.send(self.pub_socket, self.msg, ident=self.topic)
     73         self.msg = None
     74 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.pyc in send(self, stream, msg_or_type, content, parent, ident, buffers, track, header, metadata)
    647         if self.adapt_version:
    648             msg = adapt(msg, self.adapt_version)
--> 649         to_send = self.serialize(msg, ident)
    650         to_send.extend(buffers)
    651         longest = max([ len(s) for s in to_send ])

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.pyc in serialize(self, msg, ident)
    551             content = self.none
    552         elif isinstance(content, dict):
--> 553             content = self.pack(content)
    554         elif isinstance(content, bytes):
    555             # content is already packed, as in a relayed message

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/IPython/kernel/zmq/session.pyc in <lambda>(obj)
     83 # disallow nan, because it's not actually valid JSON
     84 json_packer = lambda obj: jsonapi.dumps(obj, default=date_default,
---> 85     ensure_ascii=False, allow_nan=False,
     86 )
     87 json_unpacker = lambda s: jsonapi.loads(s)

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zmq/utils/jsonapi.pyc in dumps(o, **kwargs)
     38         kwargs['separators'] = (',', ':')
     39 
---> 40     s = jsonmod.dumps(o, **kwargs)
     41 
     42     if isinstance(s, unicode):

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, encoding, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    248         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    249         separators=separators, encoding=encoding, default=default,
--> 250         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
    251 
    252 

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.pyc in encode(self, o)
    208         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    209             chunks = list(chunks)
--> 210         return ''.join(chunks)
    211 
    212     def iterencode(self, o, _one_shot=False):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I would have expected my precautions to have removed these lines, but I also don't fully understand how to work around the encoding issues.  It's fully possible that strange characters have made their way into the data, but I don't have experience dealing with encoding issues and I haven't been able to adapt any other solutions I've found online.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Well you're going to have to post raw input data, ideally of the problematic lines to reproduce your problem, you could try :`df = pd.read_csv(f_name,header=0,sep='\s+',skiprows=bad_lines,error_bad_lines=False)` just in case your separators are not just tabs, also what are you trying with `header=0`? If your csv has no header then you want `header=None`, what you've done is specify the first line is the header

Comment: One solution would be to switch to Python 3, which would help you rid 95 % of the encoding woes.

Comment: I don't believe this is an encoding issue rather either a malformed csv, or incorrect parsing params have been passed to `read_csv`

Comment: I actually didn't notice this before, but the error is not in the read statement, it's in the df.head() statement - BUT, if I write print df.head(), that works just fine.  I'm sure I'll continue to learn more about this, but I don't fully understand :)